# C# asp.net Howto load an aspx page from another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 projects. One project is a core and contains the GUI which is always the same and acts like a kind of framework.

The second project is an application that must be set in the framework.

The framework consists of a masterpage and a content page (application.aspx). From my second project I want to load the application.aspx. Is this possible? And if so.. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did very similar thing in our projects

We add the folder/files in our source safe, and share these folders/files to other projects from source safe

Comment: we will share files through VSS and files added virtually in the projects

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.Transfer("application.aspx");
```

will take you there.  What do you mean by

> load the application.aspx?

Comment: The first project contains application.aspx. I want to open this page from my second project.

Comment: You can make a symbolic reference to the other file.

Comment: I have a reference in my project. When I do server.transfer i get this error: `Error executing child request for application.aspx.`

Comment: Application.aspx is just a content page with a masterpage.